# custom-domain https requests aborted on appengine app

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, ssl

I have recently enabled https on custom domain for my appengine app. Everything worked just fine for a couple of days. After a while, on some machines requests started getting aborted.

I observed that on the machines prone to this strange behavior, the issue was reproducible only when the following conditions were met:
- access the application using https from the custom domain
- many requests were fired one after another (like adding to the DOM 30+ images, so not necessarily AJAX requests)

Also I observed that on a machine that was having the problem, if the traffic would go through fiddler, the issue would disappear.

Now: even though firing 30 requests one after another (like adding to the DOM 30 images) might not be the best of practices, is it normal for firefox and chrome to abort 80% of the requests only when using https on custom domain? If so why the requests don't get aborted when using https and the appspot.com url of the app?

Thanks,
Cristian